# override Mage_Index module

Tags: import, overrides, indexing, reindex

i need to override the Mage_Index module to reindex data in a different database. I can't find where can i override the current connection. I need to execute it via shell through "php shell/indexer -reindexall". Anyone could help me?

EDIT (info from comments):

It is needed to get an import of >900000 Products done, where the reindex kills the Shop.

Comment: All databases belongs to the same magento instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own local.xml in some folder in app/etc/connections:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <resources>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

In your code you need to run:

```
$config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config('connections/local.xml');
Mage::getConfig()->extend($config);
```

### Or

Starting magento or running magento scripts you can tell where your local.xml is located.

```
Mage::app('default', 'store', '/path/to/test/etc');
```

Comment: this will not work, if he also wants to use the index tables on the other database.

Comment: I did not get your point. Could you please explain?

Comment: Usecase 1: let the index tables create on another database.
(solved by your setting)

Usecase 2: use this index tables from a different database, when ppl request your side. But still have the normal db as mail, so if someone puts something into cart, its on the main, not the extra database.

Comment: We don't know what is his goal. If he wants to have several databases for one instance of magento, maybe it would be better to make mysql replication.

Comment: I need it because i have to import all products and reindex them in another db and than i will do the mysql replication

Comment: Why not duplicate the all database and then run replication?

Comment: No, i have to import in another db because my catalog contains more than 900000 products. And during the import and reindex the website goes down.